# sudo -E cannot excute some commands located in home dir?

Tags: sudo

symptom:

```
$ sudo -E adb
sudo: adb: command not found

$ which adb
/home/usr/opt/android/platform-tools/adb

$ sudo -E echo ${PATH}
...:/home/usr/opt/android/platform-tools

$ stat ~/opt/android/platform-tools/adb
Access: (0775/-rwxrwxr-x)  Uid: ( 1000/ usr)   Gid: ( 1000/ usr)
```

@richard, thanks. I did this:

```
$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo sh
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$ echo 'echo $PATH' | sudo -E sh
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

so it is not in the path of sudo. But how can I make the sudo respect the PATH temporarily?

Comment: Do this to find `PATH` in `sudo` environment: `sudo bash -c 'echo $PATH'` or your pipe example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not! (`/home/usr/opt/android/platform-tools` is not in the PATH within the `sudo` environment.) `${PATH}` is evaluated by your shell before `sudo` is run, thus substituting the value of `PATH` before `sudo` is started, not the value within `sudo`.

You are correct is suspecting the `PATH`. However you test gives a false answer because of the order of evaluation.

You need to do `sudo -E /home/usr/opt/android/platform-tools/adb`

Comment: how can I let sudo respect current PATH?

Comment: one way is `sudo $(which adb)` Certain environment variables can cause a security leak if preserved by sudo.

Comment: very good advice!

Comment: The answer is in the `sudoers` manual, I will not explain it here, because 1 I have not read the relevant parts, and 2 it is dangerous to the security of your computer.

Comment: I do not want permanently change this. so I do not want to touch the visudo or env_reset, etc. I think $(which cmd) is good enough

Comment: I agree. I would not touch it ether.

Answer (score 1):

As you have found, `sudo` resets `$PATH`. You could specify the full path to the utility you wish to execute, and in most simple cases, that works just fine. But there might be situations where you need to preserve `$PATH`, such as if the program needs to call other programs not found in the `$PATH` that `sudo` provides.

The simplest way to do this is:

```
sudo env PATH="$PATH" mycmd
```

This takes advantage of the shell's evaluation order. `$PATH` is expanded before `sudo` is run, so it actually becomes:

```
sudo env PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:..." mycmd
```

`sudo` then simply calls `env`, which sets `$PATH` as instructed, and then calls `mycmd`.

Note that this only works if your `sudo` access is not restricted, and you can run any command (or any `env` command anyway).